# DJANGO - redirect() not redirecting - appends the current path name to the domain

Tags: python, django, django-forms, http-post, django-registration

Basically when a ***POST*** request is made, I want to redirect to another page.

```
def sample(request): 
    if request.method != "POST":       
        return render(request,"user/sample.html")
    else:
        return redirect("https://www.djangoproject.com")
```

This code works fine when it receives a ***GET*** request but when I submit
information, instead of redirecting to the page above, it appends the the template name into the url, Something like this :

```
http://localhost:8000/sample/sample
```

No matter what I type into the `redirect()`, even completely random things it still redirects to `sample/sample`

I've created multiple django-projects and in every one of them I still get this problem.

Comment: can you show your url configuration and html page from which you post form?

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the problem, leaving this here for anyone in the future.
My problem was in the html file

```html
<form action="" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form}}
<input type="submit">
```

the `<form action="">` must be an empty string, otherwise it is going to append that to the url.

The problem had nothing to do with the `redirect()` function.